Distributed Cache Fills Logs With Errors
I have 2 WFEs with Distributed Cache.  On one of the WFEs, around 40,000 lines a minute are written to the logs with the following message.  Does anyone know how to fix what is causing this message?

Component Manager: Resolving assembly 0

The other WFE is fine; this message does not appear.
The effected WFE has significantly increased resource use.
I've tried:

Rebuilding Distributed Cache
Removing and readding the WFE to the Farm
Building a new Server and adding it the Farm


Update: the WFE, that is working well, does have this message.  However, it only happens on start up, and it only happens once.
The good WFE has the message 1800 out 2200 lines for the Correlation ID.
The bad WFE has the message 1300 out 1500 lines per Correlation ID.
